# ¿Cuál es la explicación del uso del presente simple con función de futuro?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, futuro

Esto es algo que he estado cuestionándome hace rato.

1. En Chile es común usar las formas simples con expresiones de este estilo:

   > — No me gusta el arroz.
   >   — Yo me lo **como** entonces.

   Creo que es mejor decir *yo me lo **comeré** entonces*, como una decisión espontánea al momento de hablar. (Esto, haciendo analogía a uno de los usos del futuro en inglés.)

   ¿Por qué usar las formas simples en este caso? ¿Es correcto? ¿Cuál es la aplicación gramatical correcta del presente simple?
2. A menudo me encuentro con muchos hablantes usar expresiones como:

   > — Mándame el correo.
   >   — Te lo **envío** después.

   ¿Por qué no usar *te lo **enviaré** después* o *te lo **voy a enviar** después*? 
   Para mí las formas simples indican situaciones permanentes, hechos que siempre son ciertos o generalmente usadas con un adverbio. ¿Qué uso se le atribuye realmente? ¿Habrá diferencias regionales?

Comment: En España los dos ejemplos se usan de idéntico modo. Es más, me sonarían raros si se usara el futuro.

Comment: @Ustanak ¿Por analogía de uso de tiempos del inglés no tendrías ya la respuesta?  *Next week, I start with a new job...*

Comment: @NicholasJ. Sí pero quiero saber qué ocurre en español, pues en inglés funcionan de manera bien distinta.

Comment: @Ustanak ¿A qué te refieres? El uso del presente simple para expresar acciones futuras (dentro de un rango corto generalmente) es común en muchas lenguas. A veces con la misma intención de seguridad de que aquellas cosas realmente pasarán (aunque muchas veces eso puede salirse de nuestras manos).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La gramática de la lengua española define este uso del presente como [**presente prospectivo** o **presente pro futuro**](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=puUSNXUBIDjYcmzN):

> *[...] se caracteriza por aludir a hechos posteriores al momento de la enunciación. Sin embargo, difiere del futuro en que [...] precisa de la aparición de un complemento que aporte la información necesaria para poder situar la acción en un momento posterior de la línea temporal.*

Si te fijas, en los ejemplos tienes:

> Yo me lo como **entonces**.
>
> Te lo envío **después**.

Siguiendo con la gramática:

> *Este uso del presente es característico [...] de los compromisos, así como de las afirmaciones rotundas, la descripción de planes, actuaciones previstas o programadas y otros sucesos venideros cuyo acontecimiento no se pone en duda.*

En tus ejemplos, el primero es una afirmación rotunda (yo me lo como) y el segundo es un compromiso (te lo envío después).

En [la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modo_indicativo_en_espa%C3%B1ol#Tiempo_Presente) se afirma además que:

> *La posibilidad de usar el presente con sentido de futuro es habitual en prácticamente todas las lenguas.*

De hecho, una curiosidad es que en [el idioma japonés](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_japon%C3%A9s#Gram.C3.A1tica) no existe el tiempo futuro en los verbos, sino que se usa siempre el presente de esta misma forma (complementado con expresiones que indiquen la posterioridad de la acción, o simplemente se deduce por contexto).