# En el uso de "cuando" con referencia al futuro, ¿tengo que usar el futuro en la frase principal o puedo dejar el verbo en presente?

Tags: subjuntivo, conjugación, sintaxis, conjunciones

Si lo he entendido bien, se puede utilizar el presente después de la conjunción *cuando* si se trata de de costumbres o acciones habituales, por ejemplo:

> **Cuando** **tengo** tiempo saco a pasear al perro.

Ahora lo que necesito es modificar la misma frase para demostrar que también se puede usar el subjuntivo (con la diferencia de que ahorita se trata de un periodo de tiempo indeterminado). Mi duda es: ¿tengo que usar el futuro en la frase principal o puedo dejar el verbo en presente?

> (a) Cuando tenga tiempo **sacaré** a pasear al perro.
>
> (b) Cuando tenga tiempo **saco** a pasear al perro.

Gracias

Comment: Ambos son correctas. Para mí personalmente, en este ejemplo, en el presente suena como si pasear al perro es algo que queda pendiente o tal vez un futuro próximo, con el futuro simple connotando un futuro menos preciso o más lejano. Pero no sé si es una distinción forzada o geográfica que tengo.

Comment: @guifa curioso, a mí (castellano de España) la segunda me suena mal. En cuanto a la construcción en sí, en [condicional del DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=condicional) se lee _Sin antecedente, introduce oraciones subordinadas adverbiales de tiempo, con el sentido de ‘en el momento en que’: «Voy allí cuando me canso de la comida de mi cocinero» (RRosa Sebastián [Guat. 1994]); «Cuando lo supe, suspiré de alivio» (RBastos Vigilia [Par. 1992]). Si estas oraciones expresan tiempo futuro o hipotético, se construyen en el español moderno con el verbo en subjuntivo_.

Comment: @fedorqui no lo usaría personalmente (mi castellano es fuertemente madrileño), pero considera una frase como «ya hago una cosa cuando algo pase». El presente siempre puede tener un valor futurístico, pero sobre la diferencia entre «mañana voy a hacer algo» y «mañana hago algo» seguramente algunos han escrito libros enteros.

Comment: En Aragón la idea que transmite cada construcción es la que explica @guifa en su comentario.

Comment: @guifa ah, ya entiendo. Tienes razón. Creo que el problema radica en cómo se pronuncia; mentalmente, yo en el segundo caso pongo una coma tras _tiempo_: _cuando tenga tiempo, ..._. Esta construcción es muy diferente y, en general, me parece más informal. Yo la uso como algo así como un "no me líes, ya lo haré cuando pueda".

Comment: La segunda me parece incorrecta. Decir *cuando tenga tiempo* implica que no lo tienes, y si no lo tienes, no sacas al perro, porque si lo haces, es porque tienes el tiempo. Es una contradicción.

Comment: @Ustanak OK, pero considera que aunque sea lógicamente contradictorio, el segundo ejemplo es el que usamos los chilenos siempre. No nos gusta usar el tiempo futuro cuando hay que _comprometerse_, y en cambio usamos el tiempo presente para decir lo que podría o debería pasar. Para despedirnos decimos _nos vemos_ o incluso _nos estamos viendo_ en vez de _nos veremos_. Mañana _dejo_ de fumar en vez de _dejaré de fumar_.

Comment: @Rodrigo Sí, muy cierto. En todo caso, yo sí uso el futuro como en el primer ejemplo, y de hecho creé un tema sobre lo que dices en tus últimos ejemplos.

Comment: [Presente simple y futuro](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17306/presente-simple-y-futuro)

Comment: @guifa pues visto lo visto tu comentario daría para una respuesta muy interesante : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes poner atención en el verbo tener y te dirá en qué tiempo tienes que escribir el verbo *sacar*. O bien, si quieres usar presente en *sacar*, usa presente en *tener*.

> (a) Cuando tenga tiempo, sacaré a pasear al perro.
>   (b) Cuando tengo tiempo, saco a pasear al perro.