# ¿Por qué usamos el presente para indicar una acción que ya ha finalizado?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, tiempos-verbales

Imaginad que me encuentro con un amigo al que no he visto desde hace mucho tiempo. Le podría decir:

> ¡Hola, Paco! ¡Hace siglos que **no nos vemos**!

Mi pregunta es: ¿cuál es la razón por la que usamos el presente "vemos" cuando la acción "no nos vemos" ya ha finalizado? (porque justo en ese momento nos estamos viendo). En inglés, por ejemplo, se diría:

> We **haven't seen** each other for years!

Y en francés:

> Ça fait longtemps qu'**on ne s'est pas vus**!

o incluso

> Ça **faisait** longtemps qu'**on ne s'était pas vus**!

formulación en la cual la referencia al pasado es aún más evidente.

Comment: We do use the habitual present in English but just not in that precise sentence. "Do you see Paco?" "We do see one another from time to time, but not recently"

Comment: Se usa el presente así también en el portugués: [`"Há quantos anos não nos vemos!"`](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qLBKDxae5CkC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=não+nos+vemos)

Comment: @ukemi: Y también en [italiano](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9743/sar%c3%a0-uneternit%c3%a0-e-mezza-che-non-ti-vedo-why-use-the-present-tense-vedo-to).

Comment: ***porque los siglos vienen antes del acto/acción de ver*** de la  persona. No hay que mesclar francés y inglés aqui. Solo presta a confusión. Pero es posible decir en inglés; It's ages [present] since we've seen each other. el acto de ver no se ha finalizado. Solo los siglos.

Comment: the action hasn't ended "haven't seen" is perfect present BOOM

Answer (score 2):

En el artículo de la Wikipedia [Modo indicativo en español](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modo_indicativo_en_espa%C3%B1ol), sección *Tiempo presente*, nos detalla todas las casuísticas en las que el presente del indicativo puede utilizarse. Es una lectura interesante, pues contiene por ejemplo el presente prospectivo del que se hablaba en [¿Cuál es la explicación del uso del presente simple con función de futuro?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17306/1674).

En este caso particular, creo yo que estamos en un caso de:

> El **presente habitual** indica una repetición de acciones o procesos que se dan en la época del hablante: *Me levanto a las ocho*.

O, como indican [en otro lugar](https://books.google.es/books?id=63heLVFoS4EC&lpg=PA91&ots=b01foxSf3G&dq=presente%20%22persistente%22%20espa%C3%B1ol&pg=PA91#v=onepage&q=presente%20%22persistente%22%20espa%C3%B1ol&f=false):

> Expresa acciones o procesos que se producen cíclicamente y, por lo tanto, no tienen por qué coincidir necesariamente con el momento de la enunciación:
>
> - Todos los días *salgo* a pasear
> - Frecuentemente me lo *encuentro* en la calle
> - *Van* a Londres todos los veranos.

Mi interpretación es que en este caso hay una situación habitual de no verse y a la que se está haciendo referencia. El hecho de que se vean en este momento no impide que se genere una "meta conversación" en la que se indica que habitualmente no se están viendo.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esta pregunta es un buen ejemplo de las increíbles capacidades del español para decir mucho más de lo que se está expresando verbalmente. Si la persona que dice eso tuviera que ser meticulosamente exacta y literal, obviamente al ver a su amigo tendría que considerar que la acción de "no vernos" ya ha concluido puesto que ya lo ha visto, y la frase tendría que ser:

> Hacía siglos que no nos veíamos.

Una frase que sí, es exacta, pero comparémosla con la original:

> Hace siglos que no nos vemos.

Para mí la diferencia entre ambas es lo que es hablante quiere expresar realmente con "vemos". En el primer caso se puede tomar de forma literal: ea, ya nos hemos visto, la acción de "no vernos" queda en el pasado. ¿Y en el segundo caso? Tal vez ahí lo que "no vernos" implica es algo más: "no vernos" implica no saber nada del otro, no sentarnos a tomar algo y charlar de nuestras vidas, no ponernos al día, etc. El mero hecho de ver (literalmente) a la otra persona no hace que la acción de "no pararnos a charlar" haya terminado.

Por tanto, creo que el uso del presente es simplemente la voluntad del hablante de querer hacer algo más con su interlocutor que "verlo".

Answer (score 0):

Because the constructions are about something that is currently happening that hasn't happened in a long time. Thus the verb can be in the present tense. The other option is the imperfect past (*copretérito* or *pretérito imperfecto*).

Comment: No necesariamente.  Ejemplo, a mi sobrino: A ver si nos vienes a visitar en diciembre, Paco.  Hace tiempo que no te vemos por estos rumbos.